# Elasticsearch multilevel object search Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I have a document given below.

```
{
  "my_id": "123",
  "content": {
    "name": "abc",
    "designation": "engineer"
  }
}
```

I have written Java code for elasticsearch to access the field name which is given below.

```
String field = "content.name";
String value = "abc"

SearchResponse response = esClient.prepareSearch("indexName")
                                          .setTypes("data")
                                          .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(field, value))
                                          .get();
```

But the output that I am getting for this multilevel object search empty hits. Is there a way to access multilevel objects in Java

The given query works from sense.

```
GET indexName/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
          "content.name" : "abc"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your document has the `data` mapping type?

Comment: yup the type is "data"